# Saving HTML page source as .html then displaying it in android app

Tags: android, html

I'm building an app for a client and they want me to display their terms of use from the website onto the app. So my thought was that the easiest way would be to copy and paste the whole page source and save it as a .html file, put it into the assets folder and then use webview.loadUrl(...) to display the information. However, when I do that, the app shows the raw HTML code. What is the best way to do this?

```
w = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    w.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
    //w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    WebSettings wset = w.getSettings();
    wset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //w.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F5Sx0lCxapPYZuifVa_6FvVo_5-Lb0gU4_KgsJmd8QI/pub");
    w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/terms.html");


<html>
<head>
 <title>Terms of Use - GoVeho -- Carpool & Ride Share - Save Money - Save on Gas Prices</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 style="text-align:center;">Goveho Terms of Use Agreement</h1>
            <br/><p style="margin-left:50px;">This agreement was written in English (U.S.).  To the extent any translated version of this agreement conflicts with the English version, the English version controls.<br/><br/>Date of Last Revision:  November 2011<br/><br/>Welcome to GoVeho.com, the service for people in need of a ride, or wanting to share one, to meet each other online and make arrangements to carpool, operated by Carpool, L.L.C. ("GoVeho.com"). By using the GoVeho.com Website, (the "Website") you agree to be bound by these Terms of Use (this "Agreement"), whether or not you register as a member of GoVeho.com ("Member"). If you wish to become a Member and make use of the GoVeho.com service (the "Service"), please read this Agreement. If you object to anything in this Agreement or the GoVeho.com Privacy Policy, do not use the Website or the Service. The Terms of Use are subject to change by GoVeho.com at any time, effective upon posting on the GoVeho.com Website, and your use of the Service after such posting will constitute acceptance by you of such changes.</p><br>
            <ol style="margin-left:50px;">
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Acceptance of Terms of Use Agreement</span><br/>
            <ol><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Non-electronic Copy.</span> You have the right to receive this Agreement in non-electronic form. You may request a non-electronic copy of this Agreement either before or after you electronically sign the Agreement. To receive a non-electronic copy of this Agreement, please contact us online or send a letter and self-addressed stamped envelope to: GoVeho.com, 505 Main Street, Toms River, NJ 08753.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Withdrawing Your Consent.</span> You have the right at any time to withdraw your consent to have this Agreement provided to you in electronic form.</li><br/>
            <ol>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Notice.</span> To withdraw your consent and/or request a non-electronic copy of this Agreement, please contact us online or send a letter and self-addressed stamped envelope to: GoVeho.com, 505 Main Street, Toms River, NJ 08753.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Prospective Nature.</span> Your withdrawal of consent shall be effective within a reasonable time, NOT to exceed thirty (30) days, after GoVeho.com receives your withdrawal notice described above. Your withdrawal of consent will not affect the legal validity or enforceability of the Agreement provided to, and electronically signed by you prior to the effective date of your withdrawal.</li><br/>
            </ol>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Access and Retention.</span> In order to access and retain this electronic Agreement, you must have access to the World Wide Web, either directly or through devices that access web-based content, and pay any service fees associated with such access. In addition, you must use all equipment necessary to make such connection to the World Wide Web, including a computer and modem or other access device. Please print a copy of this document for your records. To retain an electronic copy of this Agreement, you may save it into any word processing program. Via the Website, GoVeho.com will notify you of any changes in the hardware or software requirements needed to access and/or retain this Agreement that create a material risk that you will not be able to continue to access and/or retain this electronic Agreement.</li>
            </ol></li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Eligibility.</span> While you do not need to possess a valid driver’s license, you must have reached the legal driving age of your respective community to register as a Member of GoVeho.com or use the Website. Membership in the Service is void where prohibited. By using the Website, you represent and warrant that you have the right, authority and capacity to enter into this Agreement and to abide by all of the terms and conditions of this Agreement.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Membership.</span> You may become a Member of the Service at no cost. As a Member, you will have the ability to participate in all of the features and services available within the Service. </li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Term.</span> This Agreement will remain in full force and effect while you use the Website and/or are a Member. You may terminate your membership and/or subscription at any time, for any reason, by following the instructions on the Resign pages in Account Settings, or you may contact us online or send GoVeho.com written notice of termination to GoVeho.com, 505 Main Street, Toms River, NJ 08753. If you resign or cancel your membership and/or subscription via the GoVeho.com site, to help GoVeho.com analyze and improve the Service, you may be asked to provide a reason for your resignation/cancellation. You may bypass this brief resignation survey page and continue the resignation/cancellation process by clicking the “Continue Cancellation” or other similar button on the page. GoVeho.com reserves the right to terminate your membership and/or subscription at any time by sending notice to you at the email address you provide in your application for membership, or such other email address as you may later provide to GoVeho.com. All decisions regarding the termination of accounts shall be made in the sole discretion of GoVeho.com. GoVeho.com is not required to provide you notice prior to terminating your membership and/or subscription. GoVeho.com is not required, and may be prohibited, from disclosing a reason for the termination of your account. Even after your membership or subscription is terminated, this Agreement will remain in effect. All terms that by their nature may survive termination of this Agreement shall be deemed to survive such termination.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Termination.</span>  GoVeho.com may terminate this agreement at any time, with or without notice, for any reason.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Use by Members.</span> The Website is for the personal use of individual Members.  Organizations, companies, and/or businesses may become Members and may use the Service or the Website only for the purposes set forth herein. Illegal and/or unauthorized uses of the Website, including collecting usernames and/or email addresses of members by electronic or other means for the purpose of sending unsolicited email, and unauthorized framing of or linking to the Website may be investigated, and appropriate legal action will be taken, including without limitation, civil, criminal, and injunctive redress. Use of the Website is with the permission of GoVeho.com, which may be revoked at any time, for any reason, in GoVeho.com's sole discretion.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Account Security.</span> You are responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of the username and password that you designate during the Registration process, and you are fully responsible for all activities that occur under your username and password. You agree to (a) immediately notify GoVeho.com of any unauthorized use of your username or password or any other breach of security, and (b) ensure that you exit from your account at the end of each session. GoVeho.com will not be liable for any loss or damage arising from your failure to comply with this provision. You should use particular caution when accessing your account from a public or shared computer so that others are not able to view or record your password or other personal information. If you share your computer with others, you may wish to consider disabling your auto-sign in feature.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Your Interactions with Other Members.</span> You are solely responsible for your interactions with other Members. You understand that GoVeho.com does not in any way screen its Members, nor does GoVeho.com inquire into the backgrounds of its Members or attempt to verify the statements of its Members. GoVeho.com makes no representations or warranties as to the conduct of Members or their compatibility with any current or future Members. In no event shall GoVeho.com be liable for any damages whatsoever, whether direct, indirect, general, special, compensatory, consequential, and/or incidental, arising out of or relating to the conduct of you or anyone else in connection with the use of the Service, including without limitation, bodily injury, emotional distress, and/or any other damages resulting from communications or meetings with other registered users of this Service or persons you meet through this Service. You agree to take reasonable precautions in all interactions with other Members of the Service, particularly if you decide to meet offline or in person. In addition, you agree to review GoVeho.com's Safety Tips prior to using the Service. You understand that GoVeho.com makes no guarantees, either express or implied, regarding your ultimate compatibility with individuals you meet through the Service. You should not provide your financial information (for example, your credit card or bank account information) to other Members.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Content on GoVeho.com.</span><br/><br/>
            <ol>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Proprietary Rights.</span> GoVeho.com owns and retains all proprietary rights in the Website and the Service. The Website contains the copyrighted material, trademarks, and other proprietary information of GoVeho.com, and its licensors. Except for that information which is in the public domain or for which you have been given written permission, you agree not to copy, modify, publish, transmit, distribute, perform, display, or sell any such proprietary information.  Under no circumstances will you acquire any ownership rights or other interests in any content by or through your use of this site.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Reliance on Content, Advice, Etc.</span> Opinions, advice, statements, offers, or other information or content made available through the Service, but not directly by GoVeho.com, are those of their respective authors, and should not necessarily be relied upon. Such authors are solely responsible for such content. GoVeho.com does not: (i) guarantee the accuracy, completeness, or usefulness of any information on the Service, or (ii) adopt, endorse or accept responsibility for the accuracy or reliability of any opinion, advice, or statement made by any party that appears on the Website. Under no circumstances will GoVeho.com or its affiliates be responsible for any loss or damage resulting from your reliance on information or other content posted on the Website or transmitted to or by any Members.</li><br/>
            </ol></li>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Content Posted by You on GoVeho.com.</span><br/><br/>
            <ol>
            <li>You are solely responsible for the Content that you publish or display (hereinafter, "post") on the Service, or transmit to other Members. You will not post on the Service, or transmit to other Members, any defamatory, inaccurate, abusive, obscene, profane, offensive, sexually oriented, threatening, harassing, racially offensive, or illegal material, or any material that infringes or violates another party's rights (including, but not limited to, intellectual property rights, and rights of privacy and publicity). You will not provide inaccurate, misleading or false information to the Company or to any other Member. If information provided to GoVeho.com, or another Member, subsequently becomes inaccurate, misleading or false, you will promptly notify GoVeho.com of such change.</li><br/>
            <li>You understand and agree that GoVeho.com may review and delete any content, including but not limited to messages, double-blind emails, photos or profiles (collectively, "Content"), in each case in whole or in part, that in the sole judgment of GoVeho.com violate this Agreement or might be offensive, illegal, or that might violate the rights, harm, or threaten the safety of Members.</li><br/>
            <li>By posting Content to any public area of GoVeho.com, you automatically grant, and you represent and warrant that you have the right to grant, to GoVeho.com, its affiliates, licensees and successors, an irrevocable, perpetual, non-exclusive, fully paid, royalty free worldwide license to use, copy, perform, display, reproduce, adapt, modify and distribute such information and content and to prepare derivative works of, or incorporate into other works, such information and content, and to grant and authorize sublicenses of the foregoing. You further represent and warrant that public posting and use of your content by GoVeho.com will not infringe or violate the rights of any third party.</li><br/>
            <li>The following is a partial, illustrative list of the kind of Content that is illegal or prohibited on the Website. GoVeho.com reserves the right to investigate and take appropriate legal action in its sole discretion against anyone who violates this provision, including without limitation, removing the offending communication from the Service and terminating the membership of such violators. It includes, but is not limited to, Content that:<br/><br/>
            <ul>
            <li>is patently offensive to the online community, such as Content that promotes racism, bigotry, hatred or physical harm of any kind against any group or individual;</li><br/>
            <li>harasses or advocates harassment of another person;</li><br/>
            <li>involves the transmission of "junk mail", "chain letters," or unsolicited mass mailing or "spamming";</li><br/>
            <li>promotes information that you know is false, misleading or promotes illegal activities or conduct that is abusive, threatening, obscene, defamatory, slanerous or libelous;</li><br/>
            <li>promotes an illegal or unauthorized copy of another person's copyrighted work, such as providing pirated computer programs or links to them, providing information to circumvent manufacture-installed copy-protect devices, or providing pirated images, audio or video, or links to pirated images, audio or video files;</li><br/>
            <li>contains restricted or password only access pages, or hidden pages or images (those not linked to or from another accessible page);</li><br/>
            <li>provides material that exploits people under the age of 18 in a sexual or violent manner, or solicits personal information from anyone under the age of 18;</li><br/>
            <li>provides instructional information about illegal activities such as making or buying illegal weapons, violating someone's privacy, or providing or creating computer viruses;</li><br/>
            <li>solicits passwords or personal identifying information for commercial or unlawful purposes from other users; and</li><br/>
            <li>engages in commercial activities and/or sales without GoVeho.com’s prior written consent such as contests, sweepstakes, barter, advertising, and pyramid schemes.</li><br/>
            </ul></li>
            <li>Your use of the Service, including but not limited to the Content you post on the Service, must be in accordance with any and all applicable laws and regulations.</li><br/>
            <li>You may include in your Member profile any telephone numbers, street addresses, last names, URLs or email addresses.</li><br/>
            <li>You may not engage in advertising to, or solicitation for financial gain of, other Members. This includes but is not limited to solicitation or advertising to buy or sell any products or services through the Service or to attend parties or other social functions or networking for commercial purposes. You may not transmit any chain letters or junk email to other Members. Although GoVeho.com cannot monitor the conduct of its Members off the Website, it is also a violation of these rules to use any information obtained from the Service in order to harass, abuse, or harm another person, or in order to contact, advertise to, solicit, or sell to any Member without their prior explicit consent. In order to protect our Members from such advertising or solicitation, GoVeho.com reserves the right to restrict the number of emails which a Member may send to other Members in any 24-hour period to a number which GoVeho.com deem appropriate in our sole discretion.</li><br/>
            <li>All information you include in your Member profile must be accurate, current and complete.</li><br/>
            </ol></li>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Prohibited Activities.</span> GoVeho.com reserves the right to investigate and terminate your membership if you have misused the Service in the sole discretion of GoVeho.com, or behaved in a way which could be regarded as inappropriate or your conduct is unlawful or illegal. The following is a partial, illustrative list of the types of actions that you may not engage in with respect to the Service:<br/><br/>
            <ul>
            <li>You shall not impersonate any person or entity.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not "stalk" or otherwise harass any person.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not express or imply that any statements you make are endorsed by GoVeho.com without our specific prior written consent.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not use any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other manual or automatic device or process to retrieve, index, "data mine", or in any way reproduce or circumvent the navigational structure or presentation of the Service or its contents.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not post, distribute or reproduce in any way any copyrighted material, trademarks, or other proprietary information without obtaining the prior consent of the owner of such proprietary rights.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not remove any copyright, trademark or other proprietary rights notices contained in the Service.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not interfere with or disrupt the Services or the site or the servers or networks connected to the Services or the site.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not post, email or otherwise transmit any material that contains software viruses or any other computer code, files or programs designed to interrupt, destroy or limit the functionality of any computer software or hardware or telecommunications equipment.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not forge headers or otherwise manipulate identifiers in order to disguise the origin of any information transmitted through the Service.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not "frame" or "mirror" any part of the Service or the Website, without GoVeho.com's prior written authorization. You also shall not use meta tags or code or other devices containing any reference to GoVeho.com or the Service or the site in order to direct any person to any other web site for any purpose.</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not modify, adapt, sublicense, translate, sell, reverse engineer, decipher, decompile or otherwise disassemble any portion of the Service or the Website or any software used on or for the Service or cause others to do so.</li><br/>
            </ul></li>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Modifications to Service.</span> GoVeho.com reserves the right at any time to modify or discontinue, temporarily or permanently, the Service (or any part thereof) with or without notice. You agree that GoVeho.com shall not be liable to you or to any third party for any modification, suspension or discontinuance of the Service.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Blocking of IP Addresses.</span> In order to protect the integrity of the Service, GoVeho.com reserves the right at any time in its sole discretion to block Members from certain IP addresses from accessing the Website.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Member Disputes.</span> You are solely responsible for your interactions with other GoVeho.com Members. GoVeho.com reserves the right, but has no obligation, to monitor disputes between you and other Members.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Privacy.</span> Use of the Website and/or the Service is also governed by our Privacy Policy.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Disclaimers.</span> GoVeho.com is not responsible for any incorrect or inaccurate Content posted on the Website or in connection with the Service, whether caused by users of the Website, Members or by any of the equipment or programming associated with or utilized in the Service. GoVeho.com is not responsible for the conduct, whether online or offline, of any user of the Website or Member of the Service. GoVeho.com assumes no responsibility for any error, omission, interruption, deletion, defect, delay in operation or transmission, communications line failure, theft or destruction or unauthorized access to, or alteration of, user or Member communications. GoVeho.com is not responsible for any problems or technical malfunction of any telephone network or lines, computer online systems, servers or providers, computer equipment, software, failure of email or players on account of technical problems or traffic congestion on the Internet or at any Website or combination thereof, including injury or damage to users and/or Members or to any other person's computer related to or resulting from participating or downloading materials in connection with the Web and/or in connection with the Service. Under no circumstances will GoVeho.com or any of its affiliates, advertisers, promoters or distribution partners be responsible for any loss or damage, including personal injury or death, resulting from anyone's use of the Website or the Service, any Content posted on the Website or transmitted to Members, or any interactions between users of the Website, whether online or offline. The Website and the Service are provided "AS-IS" and GoVeho.com expressly disclaims any warranty of fitness for a particular purpose or non-infringement. GoVeho.com cannot guarantee and does not promise any specific results from use of the Website and/or the Service.
In addition to the preceding paragraph and other provisions of this Agreement, any advice that may be posted on the Website is for informational and entertainment purposes only and is not intended to replace or substitute for any professional financial, medical, legal, or other advice. GoVeho.com makes no representations or warranties and expressly disclaims any and all liability concerning any treatment, action by, or effect on any person following the information offered or provided within or through the Website. If you have specific concerns or a situation arises in which you require professional or medical advice, you should consult with an appropriately trained and qualified specialist.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Links.</span> The Service may provide, or third parties may provide, links to other World Wide Web sites or resources. Because GoVeho.com has no control over such sites and resources, you acknowledge and agree that GoVeho.com is not responsible for the availability of such external sites or resources, and does not endorse and is not responsible or liable for any Content, advertising, products or other materials on or available from such sites or resources. You further acknowledge and agree that GoVeho.com shall not be responsible or liable, directly or indirectly, for any damage or loss caused or alleged to be caused by or in connection with the use of, or reliance upon, any such Content, goods or services available on or through any such site or resource.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">No Third Party Beneficiaries.</span> You agree that, except as otherwise expressly provided in this Agreement, there shall be no third party beneficiaries to this Agreement.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Safety.</span>  We work hard to keep GoVeho.com safe, but we CANNOT and DO NOT guarantee it.  You shall take all necessary and reasonable precautions for your own safety, which actions shall include, but are not limited to the following commitments:<br/><br/>
            <ul>
            <li>You shall be honest about all of your registration and biographical information;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not bully, intimidate, or harass any member or user;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not use GoVeho.com to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not provide any false personal information, or create an account for anyone other than yourself;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not create more than one personal profile;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not use GoVeho.com if you are under 18, or have not reached the legal driving age;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not post content or take any action on GoVeho.com that infringes or violates someone else’s rights or otherwise violates the law;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not post anyone’s identification documents or sensitive financial or other information on GoVeho.com;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not use GoVeho.com if you are a registered sex offender;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not use GoVeho.com if you are a convicted felon;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not upload viruses or other malicious code;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not do anything that could disable, overburden, or impair the proper working of GoVeho.com, such as a denial of service attack;</li><br/>
            <li>You shall not transfer your account, share your password, let anyone else access your account, or do anything else that might jeopardize the security of your account;</li><br/>
            <li>You SHALL keep your contact and biographical information up-to-date and accurate.</li><br/>
            </ul></li>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Other.</span>  We work diligently to keep GoVeho.com up, running bug-free, and safe BUT YOU USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK.  We do not guarantee that GoVeho.com will be safe or secure.  You understand that driving has inherent risks that are not assumed by GoVeho.com.  Also, we do not certify any of the members as safe or even licensed drivers.  You connect and share rides with members AT YOUR OWN RISK.  Please see our safety section for tips that may help to make the carpooling process safer.<br><br>If Goveho.com fails to enforce any of this Agreement, it shall not be considered a waiver.  No course of action, delay, omission, or failure by GoVeho.com to exercise or otherwise enforce any provision of this agreement shall be deemed or constitute a waiver or breach, or otherwise seen to create or establish a right or remedy.<br><br>Nothing in this statement shall prevent us from complying with applicable law.  You agree to comply with all applicable laws when using or accessing GoVeho.com.<br><br>GoVeho.com reserves the right, and you authorize GoVeho.com to use and assign all information regarding site uses by you and all information provided by you in any manner consistent with our privacy policy.</li><br/>
            <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">INVALIDITY CLAUSE.</span>    This Agreement contains the entire agreement between you and GoVeho.com regarding the use of the Website and/or the Service. If any provision of this Agreement is held invalid or unenforceable, the remainder of this Agreement shall continue in full force and effect.</li>
            </ol>
            <br/><p style="margin-left:50px;text-align:center;">Please contact us with any questions regarding this agreement. GoVeho.com is a trademark of Carpool, LLC.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: loading html pages from assest folder should work. Maybe something is wrong with the html file? Does it display ok if you open the file with a "normal" browser?

Comment: I added the java and html code